# Do is recommended to create a class to open/close a connection and execute commands in a database?

Tags: c#, database

My professor of C# at a course I'm taking, told us to use a class that he wrote that open/close a connection and execute commands in a database (SQL Server and MySQL). Do is recommended to use this type of classes while developing a program, do experienced developers use this things?

Comment: Yes. But developers also use things like Entity Framework, Subsonic, NHibernate and so on and so forth. If your professor is teaching you the basics of connecting to the database, then creating connections (hopefully with `using`), commands, and iterating over data readers gives you a good appreciation of the basics. Later on, you may want to never interact directly with the database ever again, and so use a data access framework or similar to `abstract` it all away.

Comment: Don't you trust your professor?

Comment: @Magnus I humbly submit that tools developed by professional in-the-trench devs are likely to be far more suitable for everyday use than tools used by a professor in an ivory tower. I would bet a fiver that "dapper" runs circles around this profs tooling :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this recommended to use this type of classes while developing a program?

**Yes**, this kind of classes can save you a bunch of headaches in later development of program.Secondly, all database related logic comes in a single class for reusability. Also, if you make any changes to this class , then they will apply to whole program.

> Do experienced developers use this things?

**Yes**, programmers generally separate the data access layer, in a separate class or a class library depending upon the size of the project.

But, developers are not limited to only this kind of classes, they leverage the use of `ORMs` for saving them time.ORM often reduces the amount of code that needs to be written. ORMs can automate much of the `CRUD` from the application. Stored procedures are good for adding abstraction, adding a layer of security and optimizing area’s that need to be highly performant.Some ORMs can be listed as below:

- Entity Framework
- SubSonic
- NHibernate
- Dapper
- OrmLite
- PetaPoco etc

Comment: What does "ORM" means?

Comment: @Zignd, do some research! Really a matter of seconds to google it, don't be lazy.

Comment: @Zignd Added some explanation on ORM

Answer (score 2):

All experienced developers will utilise classes to maintain ease of use and re-use. The entire reason you use classes is to avoid having to re-invent the wheel every time you write a program.

Not using classes means you'll have code all over the place, making it increasingly difficult to follow and debug.

Make use of classes in your code. You will become a FAR better programmer.